# Creating diagonal border-radius

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

After searching for a while for a solution for this I've come up with none. What I'm trying to do is create a diagonal border on the first `li` element's `top left` corner.. I tried using a solution that involved the `background` property but it doesn't give me quite what I want. Also it doesn't allow any manipulation of the colors which will be needed later on.

The light blue color should be a border that gets cut (and not a background that gets cut) and the dark grey should be the background of the `li`.

How can I achieve this via CSS? A JS/Jquery solution would work as well.

**EDIT:** After seeing a lot of misinterpreted answers to my question I'll clarify it a bit:

The left image is what I have now, the right image should be the result.

[image: example pic]
[image: expected result]

```
.cal-scheme {
    width: 100%;

    li {
        width: calc(100% / 6);
        height: 150px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: $thin-blue;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;

        &:first-child {
            background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 20px, $light-blue 0);
            border: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is Your border (lightblue) inside background (darkgrey)?

Comment: @BogdanKuštan It's not. I made the background light blue so you could see the problem since the background is dark grey.

Comment: This isn't possible through `border-radius` just yet, but a proposed enhancement to this property will allow you to do exactly what you're looking for (search for "css corner shape"). In the meantime, applying this effect to a border will be somewhat nontrivial. There are a number of questions about chamfering a borderless background this way, with a solution demonstrated in Bogdan Kuštan's answer, but I'm not sure if any exist for borders.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz: I see you have already accepted an answer. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/4zy1opco/) is another approach using pseudo-elements and border-image (lesser browser support). I will add as answer if you wish.

Comment: @Harry I tried modifying your fiddle but it doesn't appear to be working unless you have a large border. Correct?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz: I have modified it a bit now again mate. Didn't see your second screenshot before posting it. Please check the same link again now. It still doesn't come out 100% correct though, the cut part of the line is either a bit thin compared to other areas or a bit thicker. So I guess, this option is still not fully usable.

Comment: @Harry I like your answer, however, after testing some manipulation of the element it's more code needed than for the already existing answer.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz: Probably yes and as I mentioned earlier the browser support for `border-image` is also pretty less, so I will leave it in comments for future reference :)

Comment: Try a svg solution (its much simpler!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand question, You need something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/q536p64b/)

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: darkgrey;
}
li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: lightblue;
    position: relative;
    border: 10px solid lightblue;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

li:first-child:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: darkgrey;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: -15px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You can't achieve with border-radius. Just using css shapes, or hacks like this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q536p64b/2/)

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: darkgrey;
}
li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: darkgrey;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid lightblue;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

li:first-child:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: darkgrey;
    border-right: 2px solid lightblue;
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    left: -17px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I need. I need the border itself to be diagonal, not the background.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py well You can't with `border-radius`. Keyword **radius** as in circle or elipsis

Comment: @BogdanKuštan - True. I was just about to comment that on the main post.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz You can't achieve with `border-radius`. Just using css shapes, or hacks like [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q536p64b/2/)

Answer (score 0):

How about achieving that like this? without `border-radius` property
**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xcpyzayt/1/)**

Also have look at **[The Shapes of CSS](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)** on css-tricks.

**HTML**

```
<div class="square">
    <div class="cut-fold"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    body {
    background: #2D2D2D;
}
.square {
    background: #5E9EE8;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
.cut-fold {
    background: #2d2d2d;
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -34px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the expected result image, both your answers (@ThePragmatick) doesn't quite achieve it better than my existing attempt.